# How to fix this Optional String error

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

How to fix this error in swift-

**unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value**

[image]

Comment: you are using SwiftyJSON, simply use `result["RewardName"].stringValue` and read the [library documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#subscript) carefully

Comment: It's giving same error and yes i am using SwiftJSON

Comment: So the problem is not in a String, but rather with your `KategoriLabel` outlet, it should be connected to your storyboard or xib

Comment: i don't have .xib extension file and label connected my storyboard

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why. I'm stackoverflow in new

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use this form while you are using SwiftyJSON.

```
result["RewardName"].stringValue
```

But before that I would check it if the "RewardName" actually exists by ;

```
if result["RewardName"] != JSON.null {
   // Your code with parsing    
}
```

Hop it helps!

Comment: It's not working. puff

Comment: @Developer Are you sure ? According to the documentation and ussage it is working perfectly. Checking if the given value is not 'nil' and then parsing it. Works fine.

Comment: I can get the data in JSON format is not nil but shows nil when I write to the screen

Comment: JSON format wont be a nil while your request from somewhere finished with success. But JSON in it selfs might not have a given property like you can see from your print stack ex. null ... null. That means JSON does not have this property.

Comment: @Developer Please mark the answer if it helps otherwise edit a question with a code. Thank you !